# How to determine the size of a set variable in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, set, size

I have code as below where table data is captured in `set(cur)`. Is there any way to find the space occupied by this variable in linux/unix? (Memory or buffer space)

```
cur.execute("select A , B , C from DeptTable")
dept_entries = set(cur)

cur.execute("select A , B , C from EmployeeTable where EmplName in ('A','B')") 
for empl in cur:
  if empl in dept_entries:
    print(empl, 'Yes')
  else:
    print(empl, 'No')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using [`sys.getsizeof`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof):

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getsizeof(dept_entries)
12345
>>> sys.getsizeof(set([1,2,3]))
224
>>> sys.getsizeof(set([1,2,3,4,5]))
736
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply.. May i know Is this size in KB or MB ?